# How to group dates which are in sequential to 'From' and 'To'?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dates in sequential and some are not in sequence. How can I group those dates to 'From date' and 'To Date'?

```
Name    Date
ABC     Jan 1, 2022
ABC     Jan 2, 2022
ABC     Jan 3, 2022
ABC     Feb 1, 2022
DEF     Jan 1, 2022
DEF     Mar 1, 2022
DEF     Mar 2, 2022
```

This should group as

```
Name      From             To
ABC   Jan 1, 2022      Jan 3, 2022
ABC   Feb 1, 2022      Feb 1, 2022
DEF   Jan 1, 2022      Jan 1, 2022
DEF   Mar 1, 2022      Mar 2, 2022
```

This is just the reverse of dates.explode (frequency day) where all the dates between two dates are converted to list of dates, but here I want to group those to 'from and to date'.

Comment: What are the rules for grouping? By month? What should happen if dates are not chronological? What's the significance of the "Name" column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `diff` with `cumsum` create the `groupby` key

```
x = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()
out = df.groupby([df['Name'],x])['Date'].agg(['first','last']).reset_index(level=0)
Out[219]: 
     Name        first         last
Date                               
1     ABC  Jan 1, 2022  Jan 3, 2022
2     ABC  Feb 1, 2022  Feb 1, 2022
3     DEF  Jan 1, 2022  Jan 1, 2022
4     DEF  Mar 1, 2022  Mar 2, 2022
```